# Using functions when calling other functions with dot syntax

Tags: lua

So we have the following functions:

```
Example.Kappa.Hydra
Example.Kappa.Titan
Example.Kappa.Kronos
```

Now I have a function which dynamically returns me the name of the last "." (These can change e.g. Hydra -> Sphinx and Titan -> Herold). What is the correct syntax to use this finding function?

What I am trying to achieve basically:

```
Example.Kappa.GetFunctionName(1) (-> Should insert "Hydra" where GetFunctionName is)
```

Answer (score 1):

`a.b` is just syntactic sugar of `a["b]`, where `a` is a table, and the string `"b"` is the key.

In your example, use the original form directly:

```
Example.Kappa[GetFunctionName(1)]
```

Comment: I already tried that but it says that i'm attempting to index an empty field (aka. the field doesn't exists)

Comment: Show [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).